# How can I write a simple example on how to use delegates in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, macos, class, delegates

I want to write a simple example on how delegates work in Swift. I've set up a class, a protocol and another class which adheres to the protocol. However I'm getting on two different places the same error. I've created a simple swift command line tool in xcode and all my code is inside main.swift. The code has no real functionality except learning how delegates work.

Here are the error messages:

> Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
>   Insert ';'
>   Expected '(' in argument list of function declaration
>   Expected '{' in body of function declaration
>   Expected 'func' keyword in instance method declaration
>   Insert 'func '
>   Expected declaration
>   Invalid redeclaration of 'delegate()' *//or anything() in the other error*

Here is the code:

```
class MainClass {

    var delegate: MyProtocol? = nil

    delegate.doAnything() //getting 1st error here
}


protocol MyProtocol {
    func doAnything()
}


class OtherClass: MyProtocol {

    let anything = MainClass()

    anything?.delegate = self //getting 2nd error here

    func doAnything() {
        print("text")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the first error is because you are trying to call the delegate function, outside of anywhere it can be executed.  You need to create a function that calls that function, or call it in init. When making examples, try using real world concepts to model your example.  You could do something like a Conductor class and a Train Class.  The conductor could implement some control protocol that controls the speed of the train.

Anyway, your second error is because `self` has not yet been initialized.  to assign a variable to `self`, you must initialize the class first, so you could do

```
init() {
   anything?.delegate = self
}
```

Feel free to DM to understand this concept more, i'll post a full example here in a bit.

EDIT: FULL EXAMPLE, feel free to ask questions

```
import Foundation

enum Direction {
    case north
    case east
    case south
    case west
}

protocol VehicleControls {
    var speed: Float {get set}
    var direction: Direction {get set}
    var numPassengers: Int {get}

    func change(newSpeed: Float)

    func change(newDirection: Direction)

    func createNoise()
}

class Conductor {
    var vehicle: VehicleControls

    init() {
        vehicle = Train(s: 1.5, d: .west, nP: 50)
    }

    func controlVehicle() {
        vehicle.change(newSpeed: 2.5)
        vehicle.change(newDirection: .east)
        vehicle.createNoise()
        print("\n")
    }
}

class Train: VehicleControls {
    var speed: Float
    var direction: Direction
    var numPassengers: Int

    init() {
        self.speed = 0
        self.direction = .north
        self.numPassengers = 0
    }

    init(s: Float, d: Direction, nP: Int) {
        self.speed = s
        self.direction = d
        self.numPassengers = nP
    }

    func change(newSpeed: Float) {
        print("changing speed from \(speed), to \(newSpeed)")
        self.speed = newSpeed
    }

    func change(newDirection: Direction) {
        print("changing direction from \(direction) to \(newDirection)")
        self.direction = newDirection
    }

    func createNoise() {
        print("Chugga, Chugga... Chugga, Chugga... CHOO CHOO")
    }
}

class Car: VehicleControls {
    var speed: Float
    var direction: Direction
    var numPassengers: Int

    init() {
        self.speed = 0
        self.direction = .north
        self.numPassengers = 0
    }

    init(s: Float, d: Direction, nP: Int) {
        self.speed = s
        self.direction = d
        self.numPassengers = nP
    }

    func change(newSpeed: Float) {
        print("changing speed from \(speed), to \(newSpeed)")
        self.speed = newSpeed
    }

    func change(newDirection: Direction) {
        print("changing direction from \(direction) to \(newDirection)")
        self.direction = newDirection
    }

    func createNoise() {
        print("HONK HONK, BEEP BEEP")
    }
}

let newConductor = Conductor()

newConductor.controlVehicle()

newConductor.vehicle = Car(s: 60.56, d: .north, nP: 2)

newConductor.controlVehicle()
```

Answer (score 0):

edit your code in playground file:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func doAnything()
}

class MainClass {

    var delegate: MyProtocol? = nil

    func callMeForGetCallBackWithDelegate() {
        // send call back inside any function after call or inside in init
        if let delegate = self.delegate {
            delegate.doAnything()
        }
    }
}


class OtherClass: MyProtocol {

    let anything = MainClass()

    init() {
        self.anything.delegate = self // set delegate in init or set inside any function
        self.anything.callMeForGetCallBackWithDelegate()
    }

    func doAnything() {
        print("text")
    }
}

let otherClass = OtherClass()
```